# VBA Excel - Enabled Sort and Filter on Protect Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to highlight a range on a protected sheet every time the user clicks on a cell of it. At the same time, I need the Filter and sorting options to be enabled.
The code below works fine for filtering but pops up a message when trying to sort, saying the sheet is protected

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Row <= 6 Then Exit Sub

Dim RS As Long

Me.Unprotect Password:=pass

Me.Range("A7:Q1048576").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

RS = Selection.Row

With Me.Range("A" & RS & ":" & "Q" & RS).Interior

.Pattern = xlSolid
.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
.PatternTintAndShade = 0

End With

Me.Protect Password:=pass, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: ***True allows the user to sort on the protected worksheet. Every cell in the sort range must be unlocked or unprotected. The default value is False.***

You'd need every single cell of your table (including the headers) to be unlocked for sorting to work while the sheet is protected. Which defeats the purpose of protecting the sheet, I bet..

What you could do is unprotect the sheet when the user selects a single cell of the row of the headers. Other than that and [using buttons with vba code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723176/sort-a-table-with-protected-sheet) to do the sorting (together with not needing to (un)protect with vba after the one time, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182031/unable-to-sort-or-filter-data-on-a-protected-sheet-with-locked-cells)), I haven't found a different method without leaving cells unlocked [like here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4673-excel-sort-filter-protected-sheet.html).
Note: if you fill a password in the "Allow users to edit ranges" part, you'd need to fill in the password after every time your code re-protects the sheet.

If you do go with the last option, you could have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Unprotect Password:="pass"
    Application.Undo
    Me.Protect Password:="pass", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Worksheet_Change doesn't get triggered by sorting/selecting.